# How to nicely cut long text using Android canvas.drawText?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-widget, android-custom-view

I'm developing my own custom control. It's rectangle with a text inside. Text could be longer then rectangle so I need to cut it. Please help me style clipped text to make it understandable that there is more text. Last characters should have opacity.

```
Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
// draw button
paint.setColor(Color.parseColor("#b33232"));
canvas.drawRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight(), paint);
paint.reset(); 

// draw text
paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
paint.setTextSize(16);
canvas.drawText("My very very long text", 5, 24, paint);
paint.reset();
```

- First image is what I have
- Second is what I need to get

[image]

Comment: Are you aware you can already get this effect with a TextView? Have a look at `android:ellipsize="marquee"`.

Comment: yeah, but I'm using Canvas. Is it possible to use this method along with drawText ?

Answer (score 3):

I think TextUtils.ellipsize is what u want.

Check this..
[TextUtils](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/TextUtils.html#ellipsize%28java.lang.CharSequence)

Comment: but how can I implement design with transparent last characters ?

Comment: i think android's fadingEdge for view can help